# Evil-mode's delete inner-sentence command deletes a paragraph

Tags: evil, sentences, paragraphs

Evil's evil-inner-sentence seems to select an entire paragraph. For instance, if I do `dis` somewhere in a paragraph it deletes the entire paragraph instead of just the sentence. This is also the case with `das`. Is there a setting I need to change to make this behave more like vim, where only a sentence is deleted?

Comment: I don't use Evil, so I can't help (and the description means nothing to me, naturally). But I'll ask whether you think an Evil user will understand clearly enough just what actions and their effects you're describing. If you think not, consider describing them step by step, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). (HTH - if not, ignore.)

Comment: The question is understandable, but I was unable to replicate the bug.  I tried `dis` on some random prose in both vim and evil, and they both worked identically as far as I could tell.  If he could provide a concrete example where vim and evil perform `dis` differently, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a variable called `sentence-end-double-space` which is set to true by default, and tells Emacs that distinct sentences are separated by two spaces, not one. Toggling that to nil fixed my issue.

Comment: Way back in the day, when I was taught touch typing, I was taught to use two spaces after a period, so that's what I've done for decades.  No wonder my own text didn't show any differences.  I'm glad you figured it out though.

Comment: Also, it seems Spacemacs might have set that to nil for me by their default.